# How to select non-consecutive text in OS X

Tags: macos

In Windows I would hold the ALT key to highlight non-consecutive (or non-contiguous) text pieces, but how can I achieve this in the latest OS X (mavericks)? If it's any consolation, I'm trying to achieve this in Word, however I'd like it to be a universal function if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem in Word (and TextEdit and other word processors...), just use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Select letters/words with mouse</kbd>:

[image]

You cannot have a universal shortcut AFAIK, because developers need to use something called [`NSTextView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in their apps (which they don't for some reason beyond me...).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I will tick if no one else comes up with a universal method. +1